# How Do I Create a New Data Frame Using Rows of Equal Length Above a Certain # From Larger Data Frame in R?

Tags: r

I started with a large data frame (828 rows x 9 columns) which relates to vegetation measurements for locations used by coyotes and random locations. I used `ddply` to arrange the data by `Coyote ID`,`Random` (Y or N) and the number of observations (`nrow`).

A few rows would look like this:

```
COYOTID    Random     nrow
1 Y 28
1 N 28
2 Y 16
2 N 12
3 Y 8
3 N 8
```

I want R to tell me for which ID's are there an equal number of observations above a certain threshold (let's say 28: in this example only ID 1). Then I want to make a new data frame from the original only keeping the rows containing these ID's. How can I do this? Everything I've looked at so far (I'm usually led to `lapply`) deals with manipulating full columns as "subsets" but not subsets of subsets.

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'COYOTID', we get the row index (`.I`) where the `length` of `unique` element in 'nrow' is 1 (`uniqueN` is a wrapper for that) and the value is greater than or equal to 28.  Using this row index column, we subset the rows.

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.6+
 setDT(df)[df[, .I[uniqueN(nrow)==1 & nrow>=28], by = COYOTID]$V1]
 #     COYOTID Random nrow
 #1:       1      Y   28
 #2:       1      N   28
```

---

Or we can use a similar approach using `dplyr`.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
   group_by(COYOTID) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(nrow)==1 & nrow >=28)
 # COYOTID Random  nrow
 #    (int)  (chr) (int)
 #1       1      Y    28
 #2       1      N    28
```